# move nodes on a treeview control

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I am using the standard asp.net treeview control to display a menu structure that is getting bound from a database. The data structure has a parentID column to represent the node relationship if one exists.

Anyway, that's not an issue, I am looking for a treeview control that would allow a user to rearrange the node by dragging them to a new position within the tree. Can anyone point me in the right direction as to any controls out there that can do this? The windows form control has the move node events. IS there something like this for web forms? Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have look at ExtJS TreePanel.

[Drag and Drop ordering in a TreePanel](http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/tree/reorder.html)

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much. It looks like the one for the job I need to do :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not try the JQuery TreeView plug-in?
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/treeview

Not sure if meets all of your non-functional requirements, but if you click on the "Try out a demonstration" link, you should be able to see if it meets your needs.